# How to remove area under the curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code for a Matplotlib plot:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

columns = ['Price']
price_values = [[4.2],
    [4.1],
    [4],
    [3.8],
    [3.9],
    [4.2],
    [4.5],
    [4.8],
    [5.2],
    [5.2],
    [5.2],
    [5.6],
    [5.2],
    [5.1],
    [5.3],
    [6],
    [6.2],
    [6.3],
    [6.2],
    [6],
    [5.5] ,
    [5.2],
    [4.8],
    [4.6]]

price_data = pd.DataFrame(price_values, index=range(0, 24), columns=columns)
fig = plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax=plt.gca()

for column,color in zip(price_data.columns,['gold']):
    ax.fill_between(
        x=price_data.index,
        y1=price_data[column],
        y2=0,
        label=column,
        color=color,
        alpha=.5,
        step='post',

        linewidth=5,
    )


ax.set_facecolor("white")
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize = 14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Price [Cent/kWh]", fontsize = 14,labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 23)
ax.set_ylim(0, 8)


plt.xticks(price_data.index, labels=[f'{h:02d}:00' for h in price_data.index], rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
hours = list(range(25))
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours]
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 1.07), fontsize = 14, ncol=3)
plt.savefig('Diagramm.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Now I would like to remove the area under the curve, sucht that I can only see the curve. I tried to use

```
plt.bar(fill=False)
```

but I get the error "TypeError: bar() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'height'". Any suggestions how I can do that

Comment: Why do you use `ax.fill_between` if you don't want to fill?  Maybe you could replace that call with `ax.step`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `fill_between` and later remove the area under the curve seems like a pretty convoluted way to plot your data. But you could just set `y2=price_data[column]`:

```
price_data = pd.DataFrame(price_values, index=range(0, 24), columns=columns)
fig = plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax=plt.gca()

for column,color in zip(price_data.columns,['gold']):
    ax.fill_between(
        x=price_data.index,
        y1=price_data[column],
        y2=price_data[column],
        label=column,
        color=color,
        alpha=.5,
        step='post',
        linewidth=5,
    )

ax.set_facecolor("white")
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize = 14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Price [Cent/kWh]", fontsize = 14,labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 23)
ax.set_ylim(0, 8)


plt.xticks(price_data.index, labels=[f'{h:02d}:00' for h in price_data.index], rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
hours = list(range(25))
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours]
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 1.07), fontsize = 14, ncol=3)
plt.savefig('Diagramm.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Edit: @JohanC rightfully noted that the last value barely appears on the plot. One way to avoid this would be to replace your loop with the following:

```
price_data.plot(ax=ax, color="gold", drawstyle="steps-mid", linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tranbi for your answer. It helped :-). I upvoted and accepted it.

Comment: Your solution is missing the last step, between 23 and 24h

Comment: @JohanC thanks for noticing! Indeed the last value is barely seen on the right side. The problem was already in OPs post though and not part of the actual question. It's a general problem with step plot. One way to overcome this would be to use plot with `drawstyle="steps-mid"`.

Comment: Wouldn't `steps-mid` cut the first and last line into two.

Comment: Yes that's right. Keeps the x-range unchanged though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your solution is missing the last price value, the one between 23 and 24 h. You'll need to repeat the last value for this to work.  To draw a step plot, the easiest way is `ax.step`.

The following example code changes the values for the first and the last value to make them stand out more.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Price']
price_values = [[1.2], [4.1], [4], [3.8], [3.9], [4.2], [4.5], [4.8], [5.2], [5.2], [5.2], [5.6], [5.2], [5.1], [5.3], [6], [6.2], [6.3], [6.2], [6], [5.5], [5.2], [4.8], [1.6]]

price_data = pd.DataFrame(price_values, index=range(0, 24), columns=columns)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
for column, color in zip(price_data.columns, ['gold']):
    ax.step(x=range(len(price_data) + 1), y=list(price_data[column]) + list(price_data[column][-1:]),
            where='post', color=color, linewidth=5, label=column)

ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Price [Cent/kWh]", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(0, 8)

xs = range(len(price_data) + 1)
ax.set_xticks(xs, labels=[f'{h:02d}:00' for h in xs], rotation=90)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.15, 1.01), fontsize=14, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Diagramm.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: ax.step]

Alternatively, you could use Seaborn's `histplot`, which has a step option (`element='step', fill=False`), but that works easiest if you'd let seaborn do the counting for the histogram. You could use `sns.histplot`'s `weights=` parameter to fill in the values, e.g.

```py
sns.histplot(x=price_data.index, weights=price_data[column].values, bins=len(price_data), binrange=(0, 24),
             element='step', fill=False, color=color, linewidth=5, label=column, ax=ax)
```